# How do kube-system pods logs get stored on the hosting node?

Tags: kubernetes

As a preface, the reason I am asking this question is that my application wants something similar: store logs on the file system of the node hosting the pods.

I read in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#system-component-logs this:

> System components inside containers always write to the /var/log directory, bypassing the default logging mechanism. They use the klog logging library.

Does `klog` somehow has a special access to /var/log? How? My application now uses standard syslog logging, and on containers this ends up writing to `stderr`.

Answer (score 2):

The question turns out to be unneeded. I looked carefully, and the logs of my application are ALSO in `/var/log/containers`. It's just that they disappear when the pods are deleted. That's my next problem to solve.

Comment: The you're looking to aggregate logs: Fluentd / td-agent is usually a good candidate reading through container logs. While it could be used forwarding logs to ElasticSearch, Splunk, ...

Comment: I agree with @SYN -- you should not be storing logs on a local filesystem, it simply will not work out well due to the distributed nature of kubernetes. But, use fluent-bit (it's part of the fluentd family but is better than fluentd itself) as a log-shipper (transporter) and something like elastic-search is pretty easy to configure as an aggregator if you don't already have one in mind.